# How to get YouTube music history with bs4?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, youtube, history

Recently I studied python and I did get YouTube music history with selenium. But it's very slow slow slow!
So I used bs4 to get history fastly.
Of course, I also used selenium for login and I want to use cookie and session information getting from selenium login. So I use `get_cookies()` method.

But the return result is not YouTube music history page but YouTube music home page.

What's the problem??
If you have any idea, please give me your idea.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

headers = {
 'User-Agent' :'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36'
}
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="openid-buttons"]/button[1]').click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys('ID')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/span').click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys('PASSWORD')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/span/span').click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.get('https://music.youtube.com/history')
time.sleep(5)

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36'})
s = requests.Session()
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
for cookie in cookies:
    s.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])
html = s.get('https://music.youtube.com/history',headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print("soup")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: If it's the case that you are being redirected to the home page instead of your music history page, then I would assume that could happen if you are not successfully logged in. Are you sure this is the id of the login button `[@id="passwordNext"]`?

Comment: i understand your reply. but i check login at the chromedriver with selenium. and it appears history.so i used Session() and cookie using cookiie and session for my login info. but i think cookie has not my info... right?

Comment: Can you expand on that? My concern is that you first call some StackOverflow page in which you enter some credentials. You then make call to this `driver.get('https://music.youtube.com/history')` which proceeds after the credentials. So are you logged in to YTMusic at this point?

Comment: hmm. i checked login YTMusic in selenium. and the reason i call stackoverflow is Google  blocked login via Automation.

Comment: This history only returns 200 musics, are you anyway interested in only retrieving such an amount? Otherwise [this link](https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity?product=26) returns more musics, are you interested in retrieving more than 200 musics?